# How Many apps we can publish with single certificate and how to update all the apps with same time

Tags: ios, app-store

Am developing applications for my customers I want to publish multiple apps for multi customer but I want to share all apps under my account with single certificate or customers accounts but i want to use single certificate for it, in future I need to update all apps with same time. I don't know how its possible. Please give some ideas. Apple store.

Answer (score 0):

You have to used the cerificate for the app which is confugird in an Apple developer account.

You can create a single (dev. or production) certificate from an apple developer account. And using that ceritificate you can create provisioning profiles to distribute or debug the app.

As per my understading of your problem, You will have different client account for different apps. So you can not merge things into one. As apple developer account are separate to each other. you can not club into one. So the app publish from a account can be manage from that account only.

What you can do is if the client is signed up as an organisation then you can invite yourself as a developer into that apple developer account. In that way you can have the access to your client's account.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but i have doubt, does it possible to use single production certificate for release multiple apps in clients developer accounts. there is any limit for release app with single production certificate?

Comment: Yes, you can. From a single release certificate. you can publish n number of apps on App Store unless it is get expired. Once expired you need to create a new one.